# copying date from one table into multiple tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'am using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`  to load all contents  to temp table called `tableA`

I got two other tables called B and C

I can easily update records in table B from A as they have  common filed called model.

Table B and C have a  common filed called productid.

How do I update the records in Table C from A?

Comment: Do you just want to add to `C` any records from `A` that weren't previously present?  Or update any records in `C` that are also present in `A`?  Or delete from `C` records that are absent from `A`?  Or some combination thereof?

Comment: i want to only update records ..

Comment: `UPDATE C JOIN B USING (productid) JOIN A USING (model) SET C.foo = A.foo ...`.